# bash - read a line, split tuples using sed/awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have text data with each line in the following form:

```
6,(2, 4, 5),(239, 153, 679)
5,(4, 5, 7),(534, 627, 902)
1,(4, 5, 6),(523, 697, 679)
3,(1, 4, 5),(942, 583, 767)
2,(3, 4, 5, 7),(239, 531, 867, 412)
4,(4, 5, 6),(253, 167, 1479)
```

I would like to read each line, split into 3 sub strings before further processing. For example, processing 1st line should yield the following 3 strings:

```
substring 1 - "6"
substring 2 - "2,4,5"  [preferably array, but I guess I can convert string to array]<br>
substring 3 - "239, 153, 67" [same as above]
```

Can someone please help ? sed and awk syntax seems to be a bit complex for me to understand at this point.

Comment: better to add your desire output.

Comment: should it literally be as `substring 1 - 6 ` ?

Comment: apart from adding exact expected output for clarity, do you need them in bash array? etc, you should also say whether you have GNU commands... if so, this would work https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html also, you have further processing.. you can add some details about that

Comment: where do those tuples  come from, python?

Comment: @S.K, please show us sample Input and expected output into code tags.

Comment: solution provided by @dogbane worked for me.The desired o/p was shown above (I added double quotes around the substrings for clarity). I can breakdown each substring into array for further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(.*),\((.*)\),\((.*)\)/\1\n\2\n\3/g' file.txt
```

Pure `bash` solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
regex="^(.*),\((.*)\),\((.*)\)$"
while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
    then
        echo "substring 1 - ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        echo "substring 2 - ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        echo "substring 3 - ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"        
    fi
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple with array:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    array1+=("$(echo "$line" | grep -oP '^\K(.+?)(?=,)')")
    array2+=("$(echo "$line" | grep -oP '^.+?,\(\K(.+?)(?=\))')")
    array3+=("$(echo "$line" | grep -oP '^.+?,\(.+?\),\(\K(.+?)(?=\))')")
done < "file.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can merge the 2 array proposal

```
#!/bin/bash
regex="^(.*),\((.*)\),\((.*)\)$"
while read line;do
if [[ $line =~ $regex ]];then
  array1+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
  array2+=("${BASH_REMATCH[2]}")
  array3+=("${BASH_REMATCH[3]}")
fi
done < "infile"
for ((i=0;i<"${#array2[@]}";i++));do
  echo "${array2[i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, another gnu **awk** solution, using **FPAT**:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; 
             FPAT="[0-9]+|\\([^()]+\\)"; 
             OFS="\n"} 
       {$1=$1;gsub(/[() ]/,"")}1' file
```

Explanation:
with the pattern `[0-9]+|\\([^()]+\\)` we describe what our fields look like, some digits OR parentheses with anything but parenteses in between.

Testing this:

```
$ echo "2,(3, 4, 5, 7),(239, 531, 867, 412)" |
> awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";FPAT="[0-9]+|\\([^()]+\\)";OFS="\n"}{$1=$1;gsub(/[() ]/,"")}1'
2
3,4,5,7
239,531,867,412
```